# Cannot access personal website from home IP. More details inside

Tags: ip-address, address

This is a recent problem I've been having.

My site can be accessed from almost everywhere else except from my home IP, where I do most of my editing/updating, etc. I've tested my connection from my school's network, a friend's connection from out of state (multiple states), and through a tethered connection with my friend's Android. It works in all those cases, both viewing, accessing the cPanel, and using FTP.

Here's the problem that happens to me when I try to view it from my home IP:

- The page times out in Firefox, IE, and Chrome.
- Using the cmd, I ran tracert and ping, both as failed attempts. Log [here.](http://pastebin.com/rkP5Dc8D)
- [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/wgxstudios.com) says my site is up. So do the other site checkers.
- I can't access my cPanel or FTP accounts.
- I can't access the host site. (I use perfectz.info for hosting, and I can't access their site either.)

System settings:

- No firewall enabled.
- Ports are seemingly properly forwarded. (e.g. The ports are open in the router settings, and are open everywhere else.)
- I have an email forwarder set up from the cPanel that **works just fine.** (i.e. I can receive emails sent to that address.

If any other information is needed, I'll do my best to provide it.

**UPDATE**

@ilhan: I use two things:

1) The site cPanel from in-browser.

2) Dreamweaver CS5 FTP.

@Matthias: I tested both, and it passes the dual stack with a 10/10. What should I do then?

Comment: Do you connect to the database from home, by using a program like Navicat for MySQL?

Comment: Maybe your server runs in dual stack mode (IPv4 and IPv6)? You can [check here][1] if your router handles it correctly. (You only need to pass the dual stack test, not IPv6-only.)

  [1]: http://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a routing/network issue with your hosting company, possibly related to their connection providers. I was able to access your site earlier, but now i can't connect.

If you are with Cablevision and know a friend who has a home connection with them, ask them to visit your site, tracert, etc to compare. Contact your hosting provider and ask them if they are aware of any routing problems.